# Visual bug in QTextEdit

Tags: c++, qt

When I try to copy and paste a text that has a line break from Google drive (docx document) to a QTextEdit in QtCreator the lives overlap

**Example**

This the text in google drive:

```
Line one
another line
final line
```

This is how it looks when i paste in a QTextEdit from QtCreator:

[image]

Inspecting the text in binary, I could see that exists a Line Feed (10 from the ASCII table), it's the same of a text where the lines don`t overlap.

I'm using QtCreator 4.11.1(Community), this only happens with a text from docx.

I didn`t make any changes in the Widget

How can I make the lines not overlap?

Comment: Please correct the question if I misinterpreted how the source file is formatted.

Comment: Which OS? What are line endings are from google drive? This looks like Windows and line endings from paste text are Linux like. Is this a plain text or rich text?

Comment: Im using Windows, i thought that a CR was missing, but when i inspected a text where the lines don`t overlap, i saw that there was only LF too

Comment: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-52604